# PowerShell function to find the square of a number:

Tags: function, powershell

This is my function for finding the square of a value:

```
function Get-Square($value)
{
    $result = $value * $value
    return $result
}

$value = Read-Host 'Enter a value'
$result = Get-Square $value
Write-Output "$value * $value = $result"
```

> ```
> PS C:\Users> .\Get-Time.ps1
> Enter a value: 4
> 4 * 4 = 4444
> ```

Why is the result 4444 and not 16? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `Read-Host` is returning a string, and a *string* times any *value* in powershell, results in *string* repeated *value* times.  You need to make powershell treat  `$value` as an integer. Try this:

```
function Get-Square([int]$value)
{
    $result = $value * $value
    return $result
}

$value = Read-Host 'Enter a value'
$result = Get-Square $value
Write-Output "$value * $value = $result"
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the Alistair's answer about converting, the `string` returned by `Read-Host` to `int`, you might want to use the Math library to square the value.

### Sample Code

```
function Get-Square([int] $value)
{
    $result = [Math]::Pow($value,2)
    return $result
}

$value = Read-Host 'Enter a value'
$result = Get-Square $value
Write-Output "$value * $value = $result"
```

### Results

> Enter a value: 4 
>      4 * 4 = 16

Answer (score -1):

It is like "4" * "4", and PowerShell converts the second "4" to int, so it returns "4444".

```
4 * 4 = 16
"4" * "4" = "4444"
"4" * 4 = "4444"
4 * "4" = 16
```